# http status 302 error in tomcat eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, telecommunication

I am developing a Telco application (Dyanamic Web application project to send and receive sms) using Eclipse & tomcate version 7

When I try to run it on

```
http://localhost:8080/SMS1
```

It gives an error message `HTTP-ERROR-CODE:302`
What should I do to resolve this error

This is the link to Application and video tutorial what I am following
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VmCeqDC7SDcFZaWVZhRUNmaTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

HTTP code 302 is a standard "redirect" message--that is, it tells your web browser that the page was moved and where the new page can be found. I'm guessing whatever you're using as a web browser (Eclipse?) just doesn't handle that type of redirect. Try using a standard web browser like Chrome or Mozilla to see if that helps...

Also a guess, but the redirect may be trying to move you to HTTPS instead of HTTP, and your certificates may not be set up properly, or the port isn't enabled, or there may be some other problem with your HTTPS configuration. If the app is supposed to work over HTTPS, try going directly to the HTTPS version of the link to see if that's the real issue.

A third guess is the app may be trying to redirect you to a login page if you're not logged in, and maybe it can't find it. I'd need to know a lot more about the built product and I really don't want to mess with some guy's shared Eclipse project. Tell them to use a build tool!

Comment: When I run it on eclipse it doesn't give any error.First it gives Error 404 and I move my jsp file into WebContent from WEB-INF.Then it work fine (as mention in the video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59ayVSP059Y&feature=youtu.be)  But when I run it on chrome(simulator).It gives 302 and sometimes 404

Comment: They're seriously sharing their code as an Eclipse Project instead of using a build tool like Maven or Ant? That complicates things. It would be hard to know what's going on without seeing you built project structure.

Comment: This is my project structure my project is named as SMS1 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VmCeqDC7SDcFJyVnFLZ2k4NlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VmCeqDC7SDNFZka2JRTm8tbjQ/edit?usp=sharing